# React Hooks (Rendering Arrays) - Parent component holding a reference of children that are mapped vs Parent component holding the state of children

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have been learning hooks in react for the past couple of days, and I tried creating a scenario where I need to render a big grid on screen, and update the background color of the nodes depending on the action I want to take. There are two actions that will change the background color of a node, and these two actions must coexist.

- The cursor hovers a node while it is clicked.
- There exists an algorithm inside the *Grid* component that will change backgrounds of some of the 
  nodes.

The way I see it, there are multiple ways I can achieve this, but I am having some trouble with the way hooks were intended to be used. I will first walk you through my thought process on how this could be achieved from what I learned, and then show you the implementation that I tried. I tried to keep the important parts of the code so it can be understood clearly. Please let me know if I missed somethings or misunderstood a concept completely.

1. The children can hold their own state and know how to update themselves. The parent can hold the reference to each children of the list, and call the necessary function from the reference of the child when it is needed in order to update the children.

   - Works well for the first and the second action to be taken. This solution causes no performance issues since the children manage their own state, and if the parent updates the children state via reference, the only child to be re-rendered will be the one that gets called.
   - This solution is seen as an anti-pattern from what I read.

```
    const Grid = () => {
        // grid array contains references to the GridNode's

        function handleMouseDown() {
            setIsMouseDown(true);
        }

        function handleMouseUp() {
            setIsMouseDown(false);
        }

        function startAlgorithm() {
            // call grid[row][column].current.markAsVisited(); for some of the children in grid.
        }

        return (
            <table>
                <tbody>
                {
                    grid.map((row, rowIndex) => {
                            return (
                                <tr key={`R${rowIndex}`}>
                                    {
                                        row.map((node, columnIndex) => {
                                            return (
                                                <GridNode
                                                    key={`R${rowIndex}C${columnIndex}`}
                                                    row={rowIndex}
                                                    column={columnIndex}
                                                    ref={grid[rowIndex][nodeIndex]}
                                                    onMouseDown={handleMouseDown}
                                                    onMouseUp={handleMouseUp}
                                                />
                                            );
                                        })
                                    }
                                </tr>
                            );
                        }
                    )
                }
                </tbody>
            </table>
        );
    };

    const GridNode = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
        const [isVisited, setIsVisited] = useState(false);

        useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
            markAsVisited: () => {
                setIsVisited(!isVisited);
            }
        }));

        function handleMouseDown(){
                setIsVisited(!isVisited);
            }

        function handleMouseEnter () {
                if (props.isMouseDown.current) {
                    setIsVisited(!isVisited);
                }
            }

        return (
            <td id={`R${props.row}C${props.column}`}
                onMouseDown={handleMouseDown}
                onMouseEnter={handleMouseEnter}
                className={classnames("node", {
                    "node-visited": isVisited
                })}
            />
        );
    });
```

2. The state of the children could be given as props from the parent, any update operation can be achieved inside the parent. (Children gets updated correctly, render gets called in only the necessary children, but the DOM seems to stutter. If you move the mouse at a certain speed, nothing happens, and every visited node gets updated at once.)

- Doesn't work for the first action. Children gets updated correctly, render gets called in only the necessary children, but the DOM seems to stutter. If you move the mouse at a certain speed, nothing happens and every visited node gets updated at once.

```
    const Grid = () => {
        // grid contains objects that have boolean "isVisited" as a property.

        function handleMouseDown() {
            isMouseDown.current = true;
        }

        function handleMouseUp() {
            isMouseDown.current = false;
        }

        const handleMouseEnterForNodes = useCallback((row, column) => {
            if (isMouseDown.current) {
                setGrid((grid) => {
                    const copyGrid = [...grid];

                    copyGrid[row][column].isVisited = !copyGrid[row][column].isVisited;

                    return copyGrid;
                });
            }
        }, []);

        function startAlgorithm() {
            // do something with the grid, update some of the "isVisited" properties.

            setGrid(grid);
        }

        return (
            <table>
                <tbody>
                {
                    grid.map((row, rowIndex) => {
                            return (
                                <tr key={`R${rowIndex}`}>
                                    {
                                        row.map((node, columnIndex) => {
                                            const {isVisited} = node;

                                            return (
                                                <GridNode
                                                    key={`R${rowIndex}C${columnIndex}`}
                                                    row={rowIndex}
                                                    column={columnIndex}
                                                    isVisited={isVisited}
                                                    onMouseDown={handleMouseDown}
                                                    onMouseUp={handleMouseUp}
                                                    onMouseEnter={handleMouseEnterForNodes}
                                                />
                                            );
                                        })
                                    }
                                </tr>
                            );
                        }
                    )
                }
                </tbody>
            </table>
        );
    };

    const GridNode = ({row, column, isVisited, onMouseUp, onMouseDown, onMouseEnter}) => {
        return useMemo(() => {
            function handleMouseEnter() {
                onMouseEnter(props.row, props.column);
            }

            return (
                <td id={`R${row}C${column}`}
                    onMouseEnter={handleMouseEnter}
                    onMouseDown={onMouseDown}
                    onMouseUp={onMouseUp}
                    className={classnames("node", {
                        "node-visited": isVisited
                    })}
                />
            );
        }, [props.isVisited]);
    }
```

I have two questions that I want to ask on this topic.

1. In the first implementation; the parent component doesn't re-render when a node changes its' state. Is it wrong to just utilize this anti-pattern if it is beneficial in this kind of situations?
2. What may be the cause of the stutter that the second implementation suffers from? I have spent a while reading the docs and trying out different things, but cannot find the reason of the stuttering that is happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you say that using refs to control child data is an anti-pattern, However it doesn't mean that you cannot use it.

What it means is that if there are better and more performant means, its better to use them as they lead to better readability of the code and also improve debugging.

In your case using a ref definitely makes it easier to update state and also prevents a lot of re-rendering is a good way to implement the above solution

**What may be the cause of the stutter that the second implementation suffers from? I have spent a while reading the docs and trying out different things, but cannot find the reason of the stuttering that is happening.**

A lot of the problem in the second solution arise from the fact that you define functions which are recreated on each re-render and hence cause the entire grid to be re-rendered instead of just the cell. Make use of useCallback to memoize these function in Grid component

Also you should use `React.memo` instead of `useMemo` for your usecase in GridNode.

Another thing to note is that you are mutating the state while updating, Instead you should update it in an immutable manner

Working code:

```
const Grid = () => {
  const [grid, setGrid] = useState(getInitialGrid(10, 10));
  const isMouseDown = useRef(false);
  const handleMouseDown = useCallback(() => {
    isMouseDown.current = true;
  }, []);

  const handleMouseUp = useCallback(() => {
    isMouseDown.current = false;
  }, []);

  const handleMouseEnterForNodes = useCallback((row, column) => {
    if (isMouseDown.current) {
      setGrid(grid => {
        return grid.map((r, i) =>
          r.map((c, ci) => {
            if (i === row && ci === column)
              return {
                isVisited: !c.isVisited
              };
            return c;
          })
        );
      });
    }
  }, []);

  function startAlgorithm() {
    // do something with the grid, update some of the "isVisited" properties.

    setGrid(grid);
  }

  return (
    <table>
      <tbody>
        {grid.map((row, rowIndex) => {
          return (
            <tr key={`R${rowIndex}`}>
              {row.map((node, columnIndex) => {
                const { isVisited } = node;
                if (isVisited === true) console.log(rowIndex, columnIndex);
                return (
                  <GridNode
                    key={`R${rowIndex}C${columnIndex}`}
                    row={rowIndex}
                    column={columnIndex}
                    isVisited={isVisited}
                    onMouseDown={handleMouseDown}
                    onMouseUp={handleMouseUp}
                    onMouseEnter={handleMouseEnterForNodes}
                  />
                );
              })}
            </tr>
          );
        })}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  );
};

const GridNode = ({
  row,
  column,
  isVisited,
  onMouseUp,
  onMouseDown,
  onMouseEnter
}) => {
  function handleMouseEnter() {
    onMouseEnter(row, column);
  }
  const nodeVisited = isVisited ? "node-visited" : "";
  return (
    <td
      id={`R${row}C${column}`}
      onMouseEnter={handleMouseEnter}
      onMouseDown={onMouseDown}
      onMouseUp={onMouseUp}
      className={`node ${nodeVisited}`}
    />
  );
};
```

[image: Edit FORM VALUES]

P.S. While `useCallback` and other memoizations will help give to some performance benefits it will still not be able to overcome the performance impacts on state updates and re-render. In such scenarios its better to make define state within the children and expose a ref for the parent

Comment: I appreciate your answer. However, I still have some questions in my head. Even if you utilize `useCallback` for function recreations, it still looks like it stutters if you have a big enough grid for your sandbox example (for example a 70x70 grid). I tried doing that after reading docs and got the same result. I created a clone of the sandbox you created which was implemented using the first method ([link](https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-currying-etjsg)).

Comment: For my second question, what is the difference between React.memo and useMemo? I know one is a HOC and therefore can be used with class components, but I don't think I read any other difference than that.

Comment: With this solution, the parent controls everything, including rendering, but in doing so through `setState`, causes the node tree to re-render each time the state is set. React will figure out which nodes it needs to re render, but there is a performance trade off as it scales.

Comment: @Pirhan, memo gives you a flexibility to implement a custom areEqual function that helps in writing more complicated logic whereas useMemo just performs a shallow comparison based on dependency array. Also useMemo's main purpose is to memoize computation. Also as I said, the second approach is is bound is take a hit since the rendering logic is in the parent and state updates and computations on re-render will be expensive. In such scenarios its better to go with the first approach for keeping state in child and exposing refs

Answer (score 0):

As stated, the solution is an anti-pattern because you're mixing the rendering and business logic on both levels. You don't need to explicitly use `React.forwardRef`, in fact according to the docs you shouldn't, even when composing HOC (Higher order components). You shouldn't need to directly access the element and do some sort of action on it - let React do its thing. It's very good and efficient at it.

Generally when you're calling a re-render method on a child node tree when there's n nodes, you don't want to cause a re-render from the top-level node, the parent in this case, because it will cause the entire node-tree to re-render into a new DOM element, rather than update existing elements.

Your current solution has a combination of parent-triggered renders and child triggered renders. The React page has a good example with the tic-tac-toe application for how to render children without causing the parent to re-render.

The strategy that you should use is one where the parent node has an object structure, in this case n^2 nodes (eg 10x10 for arguments sake), is to pass the rendering functionality to the child nodes, and let the child nodes handle the rendering.

When you're triggering a render from the parent node, you have a couple of options (assuming functional components) which really fall into the case of observable updates. You want to be able to push updates from the parent to the child, to modify the child node state, and let the child node update itself.

Here's an example with child nodes rendering, while the parent is communicating changes to the children. You'll see that the performance scales well even up to massive grids, compared to the nested level renders your example has.

https://codepen.io/jmitchell38488/pen/pogbKEb

This is achieved by using a combination of RxJS observable/subject, `React.useState` and `React.useEffect`. We use `useState` in both the parent and child nodes to deal with rendering and prop updates, and `useEffect` to bind the observable. `useState` is persistent between renders, which means you don't need to rebuild the entire grid every time you update in the parent, but even if you do, React is intelligent enough to determine that you updated the props of a node, not replaced it.

```
const Grid = (props) => {
  // When we update the grid, we trigger the parent to re-render
  const [grid, setGrid] = React.useState([]);
  const subject = new Rx.Subject();
  if (grid.length < 1) {
    const newGrid = [];
    for (i = 0; i < props.h; i++) {
      for (k = 0; k < props.w; k++) {
        if (!Array.isArray(newGrid[i])) {
          newGrid[i] = [];
        }

        newGrid[i][k] = {
          visited: false,
          id: `${i}${k}`
        };
      }
    }
    setGrid(newGrid);
  }

  // Tell our node to update
  handleClick = (node, visited) => {
    subject.next({
      id: node.id,
      visited: visited
    })
  };

  randomSetAllVisited = () => {
    const newGrid = [...grid];
    newGrid.forEach(row => {
      row.forEach(node => {
        node.visited = Math.random() * 2 >= 1;
      })
    })

    // Tell parent to re-render
    setGrid(newGrid);

    // Because our nodes use `useState`, they are persistent, if the structure of
    // grid is the same and the data is mostly the same. This is based on the `key={...}` value
    // in row.map, so we need to tell our children nodes to re-render manually
    subject.next({
      reset: true
    })
  };

  randomSetAnyVisited = () => {
    const h = Math.floor(Math.random()*props.h);
    const w = Math.floor(Math.random()*props.w);
    const node = grid[h][w];
    subject.next({
      id: node.id,
      visited: true
    });
  };

  // Watch console.log to see how frequently parent renders
  console.log("rendering parent");

  return (
    <div>
      <table>
        <tbody>
          {grid.map((row, rowIndex) => (
            <tr key={`R${rowIndex}`}>
              {row.map((node, columnIndex) => (<GridNode {...node} observer={subject.asObservable()} key={node.id} />))}
            </tr>
          ))}
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <button onClick={randomSetAllVisited}>Random set all visited</button>
      <button onClick={randomSetAnyVisited}>Random set any visited</button>
    </div>
  );
};

const GridNode = (props) => {
  // We need to set to undefined to handle full grid reset from parent
  const [visited, setVisited] = React.useState(undefined);

  // Toggle visited based on props and if visited is undefined
  if (props.visited !== visited && visited === undefined) {
    setVisited(props.visited);
  }

  // bind all this with useEffect, so we can subscribe/unsubscribe, and not block rendering, `useEffect` is a good practice
  React.useEffect(() => {
    // notifications that come from parent node, `setVisited` will re-render this node
    const obs = props.observer.subscribe(next => {
      if (!!next.id && next.id === props.id) {
        setVisited(next.visited !== undefined ? next.visited : !visited);
      } else if (!!next.reset) {
        setVisited(undefined);
      }
    });
    return () => obs.unsubscribe();
  }, [visited]);

  handleMouseEnter = () => {
    setVisited(!visited);
  }

  handleMouseLeave = () => {
    setVisited(!visited);
  }

  classes = ["node"];
  if (visited) {
    classes.push("node-visited");
  }
  return (<td onMouseEnter={handleMouseEnter} onMouseLeave={handleMouseLeave} className={classes.join(" ")}/>);
}
```

In the codepen example, I have a 50x50 grid, that has no stutters, lag, or issues re-rendering the children nodes, or updating them. There are two helper buttons to randomise the state for all nodes, or randomise a single node. I've scaled this over 100x100 and no lag or performance issues.

Comment: First of all, thanks for your answer, but I want to clarify some points. You said that if I re-render from the top-level node, it would cause the entire node tree to re-render. But if i am using `React.memo`, would it not solve this issue since it acts as `shouldComponetUpdate` in this case?

I thought that if I use `React.memo` on the nodes, it would decide whether the node is going to be re-rendered or not, therefore the parent re-rendering wouldn't be a problem. If this is not the case, what is the point of using it ever?

Comment: It's a performance optimisation function that prevents repeated renders. Can it be used in this case with `useState` and `useEffect` - yes, and it would improve performance, but don't rely on it to prevent re-renders. Ideally you want to avoid rendering the entire node tree over, and there are several strategies to do that.

Comment: So I basically want to make sure that all of the components work correctly and performant without the `memo`, and then use it to further improve the performance. Which also makes sure I don't rely on it not to re-render. Did I understand you correctly? Also, one last question; are there ways I can achieve this without using RxJS? I do like the idea and the implementation of RxJS for state management, but I also am just curious.

Comment: Use React.memo to do it without rxjs, remove `useState` from the nodes and make them pure functions. Memo performance optimisation is really there for components that have an expensive computation, the parent has, but not the children. It's not really there to prevent renders. You should use a ClassComponent to do it. Also, use rxjs, it'll make your life so much easier doing this sort of stuff.

Comment: @Pirhan If you play with the codepen, you can scale out to 100x100 grid and still no adverse performance impact, even on mobile devices.

Comment: I had a long thought about this approach, and I came to the conclusion that RxJS may not be the solution that I was looking for. The RxJS provides an event based flow, and react is known as data-driven and as far as I can tell, doesn't like to be treated as event driven. In this case, this approach makes the state of the children that is held inside the parent redundant. It serves no purpose unless the child is resetted using RxJS and makes it harder to debug. I decided to expose refs using react tools instead of using an external library. Thank you for your time!

Comment: That's a common misconception of events vs data and that React can only deal with data driven changes. Event driven applications benefit from asynchronous behaviour, one of the areas that React struggles, as it's a synchronous library. There's some serious complexity issues with RxJS, but it is a very powerful and valid tool for bringing asynchronous behaviour to an application, and is often a simpler solution for problems like this. https://medium.com/@jasbirshergill23/lets-react-with-rxjs-82d9794d76f4